# WPF Tree Datatemplate Depending on Type of Item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM WPF application with a tree containing self referenced data, this data is bound to the tree with a hierarchical converter.
(As in example: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radtreeview-how-to-bind-to-self-referencing-data.html)

This data includes ID, ParentID, Text and Type (and more).

Example Data:

```
1,0,"FirstItem","Triangle"
2,1,"SubItem1","Circle"
3,1,"SubItem2","Square"
4,2,"SubItem11","Triangle"
5,2,"SubItem12","Heart"
6,3,"SubItem21","Circle"
```

Now I would like to have different templates for the Triangles, Hearts, Circles and Squares.
I dont mean only change a Image, but really a Template.
How can i accomplish such?

Kind regards, Paul.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `DataTemplateSelector`: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2bd054fe-2fb6-47ed-be8f-26545c07e655/

Answer (score 7):

If your `ItemsSource` is made up of different Types, then you can simply create `HierarchicalDataTemplates` and not assign an x:Key.  If there is no x:Key attribute for a `DataTemplate`, the framework will use this `DataTemplate` when it comes across the type and tries to visually display it (you can read more about implicit `DataTemplates` [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403194858/http://blogs.magnatis.com/tag/datatemplate)).  For example, if you have a type Circle and another type Square, you would have the following templates in your Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Circle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Fill}" Width="25" Height="25" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.25"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Square}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}" Width="25" Height="25" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.25"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then if your `TreeView` encounters one of these Types in its `ItemsSource`, it will use the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for that specific type.

You can read more about `HierarchicalDataTemplates` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx), and [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) has an example of how they are used in a `TreeView`.

**OR**

If your items are all the same Type, and only differentiated by a property (such as Type), you'll need to use a `DataTemplateSelector`.  Here is a simple example of one:

codebehind:

```
public class ShapeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate CircleTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SquareTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Shape shape = item as Shape;
        if (shape != null)
        {
            if (shape.Type == "Circle")
                return this.CircleTemplate;
            else if (shape.Type == "Square")
                return this.SquareTemplate;
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<local:ShapeTemplateSelector x:Key="shapeSelector">
    <local:ShapeTemplateSelector.CircleTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Shape}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Fill}" Width="25" Height="25" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.25"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </local:ShapeTemplateSelector.CircleTemplate>
    <local:ShapeTemplateSelector.SquareTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Shape}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}" Width="25" Height="25" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.25"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </local:ShapeTemplateSelector.SquareTemplate>
</local:ShapeTemplateSelector>
```

Then in your `TreeView`, you simply assign the selector

```
<TreeView x:Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}" ItemTemplateSelector="{DynamicResource shapeSelector}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have actual different types, you can specify the type in the HierarchicalDataTemplate using DataType attribute ([How do I use the DataType property on a WPF DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424554/how-do-i-use-the-datatype-property-on-a-wpf-datatemplate)) and WPF will select the template based on the class.

If you don't have different types, but will depend on a property or value inside the class, you'll need to specify a DataTemplateSelector (http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)