# WPF - node style dependent from deep in tree

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

I'm looking for information about styling TreeView in WPF. I would like to set different text color for each of level of tree. I have tree with 3 levels.

Example:

-> Root (black)
    -> Level 1a (red)
      -> Level 2a (green)
      -> Level 2b (green)
    -> Level 1b (red)
      -> Level 2c (green)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341728/wpf-tree-datatemplate-depending-on-type-of-item/15344099#15344099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the color (Foreground or Background) on a view model property with custom logic.

In your case you must compute the level with a little logic : find the parent view model's level and add 1 or return 0 if parent is null.

If you are new on WPF and treeview I highly recommend to read this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode