# Xamarin.Forms can you make type related datatemplates?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, controls, declarative

In WPF you can create a DataTemplate, put it in a ResourceDictionary, assign it a Type and then bind data of that type to a ContentControl and the DataTemplate will be used to render. as in this example:
[How do I use the DataType property on a WPF DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424554/how-do-i-use-the-datatype-property-on-a-wpf-datatemplate)

the Xamarin.Forms enterprise apps ebook hints at such an ability but does not show any example: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm/#Creating_a_View_Defined_as_a_Data_Template

Can this be done in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `x:DataType` does not working with Xamarin Forms.
(I tried many different ways, but fail.)

You should implement [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netcore-3.1)

### ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:Solution.Forms"
                    x:Class="Mango.Forms.LayerDataTemplate">

    <!--#region RectLayerView -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RectLayerDataTemplate">
        <forms:RectLayerView forms:ValueX="{Binding ValueX}"
                             forms:ValueY="{Binding ValueY}"
                             forms:ValueWidth="{Binding ValueWidth}"
                             forms:ValueHeight="{Binding ValueHeight}"
                             forms:MangoColor="{Binding Color}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--#endregion-->
    
    <forms:LayerDataTemplateSelector x:Key="LayerDataTemplateSelector"
                                     RectLayerTemplate="{StaticResource RectLayerDataTemplate}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

### DataTemplateSelector.cs

```
public class LayerDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate RectLayerTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (item is RectLayerViewModel)
            return RectLayerTemplate;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector)

Comment: x:Datatype can be used with newer versions, see [Use compiled bindings in a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate)

Comment: @Benl compiled bindings does not working as expected. I add `[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]` in _App.xaml.cs_. And add `x:DataType` in _<DataTemplate />_ like this, `<DataTemplate x:Key="PathLayerDataTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:PathLayerViewModel}">`.

Comment: @Benl I made a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165144/xamarin-forms-compiled-bindings-does-not-work-on-datatemplate)