# use `x:Name` with ResourceDictionary.xaml.cs generate "cannot convert from 'Solution.Project.ResourceDictionary' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Element'" error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

What I am trying to do is access all `DataTemplate` in code behind like below.

```
public partial class LayerDataTemplate : ResourceDictionary
{
    public LayerDataTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        var templates = FindTemplatesByName(this); // magical method that using reflection to find templates by name.
        foreach(var template in templates)
        {
            this.LayerDataTemplateSelector
                .DataTemplateList
                .Add(template);
        }
    }
}
```

After I crate a code behind for `ResourceDictionary`, I got an error message like below.

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Solution.Project.LayerDataTemplate' to 'Xamarin.Forms.Element'

Error comes from **LayerDataTemplate.xaml.g.cs**, which is auto-generated. I know [`ResourceDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.resourcedictionary?view=netcore-3.1) does not inherit `Xamarin.Forms.Element`. Then how can I access `RectLayerDataTemplate` instance without `x:Name`?

### LayerDataTemplate.xaml.g.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LayerDataTemplate));
    // Error
    RectLayerDataTemplate = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate>(**this**, "RectLayerDataTemplate");
}
```

### LayerDataTemplate.xaml.cs

```
namespace Solution.Project
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LayerDataTemplate : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public LayerDataTemplate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

### LayerDataTemplate.xaml

```
    <!-- remove `x:Name`, error does not generated  -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RectLayerDataTemplate" x:DataType="DataTemplate" x:Name="RectLayerDataTemplate">
        <forms:RectLayerView forms:ValueX="{Binding ValueX}"
                             forms:ValueY="{Binding ValueY}"
                             forms:ValueWidth="{Binding ValueWidth}"
                             forms:ValueHeight="{Binding ValueHeight}"
                             forms:Color="{Binding Color}" />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: You could use `x:Key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data templates can also be created as reusable objects in a `ResourceDictionary`. This is achieved by giving each declaration a unique `x:Key` attribute, which provides it with a descriptive key in the ResourceDictionary.

The `DataTemplate` is assigned to the `ItemTemplate` property by using the `StaticResource` markup extension.

For example:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
             <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    ...
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    ...
    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}" Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            ..
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Update1**:

Try to do like this in your behind codes.

```
var myTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["myTemplate"];//myTemplate is x:Key you defined in your xaml.
```

**Update 2**:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class LayerDataTemplate : ResourceDictionary
{
    public DataTemplate template;
    public LayerDataTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       template = (DataTemplate)this["labelTemplate"];
    }
}
```

in xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"         
         x:Class="EntryCa.LayerDataTemplate">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemplate">
         <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                   TextColor="Red"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />      
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. I updated my question. `x:Key` only visible to XAML not to code behind. Or, is there a way to do it?

Comment: @ibocon Do you mean you want get the DataTemplate in your behind code ?You could check above what i update.

Comment: I mean access DataTemplate from `ResourceDictionary` code behind, not from `ContentView` or `ContentPage`. `var rectLayerDataTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["RectLayerDataTemplate"];` shows a error **The name 'Resources' does not exist in the current context.**

Comment: Or, can you check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47215805/)? The reason why I am doing this because I can not use `x:DataType` unlike WPF.

Comment: The update is used in page.xaml.cs，and DataTemplate is defined in ResourceDictionary in page.xaml

Comment: @ibocon I update again,you could check it,is it what you need ?

Comment: x:Datatype can be used with newer versions, see [Use compiled bindings in a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate)

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thanks for your help! I have a question with this, why only`Xamarin.Forms.Element` can use `x:Name`? Is it not implemented yet, or architecture based reason?